# C++ using cin.ignore() to remove first non-int from the input stream

Tags: c++, cin

So For example if I input:
33a
and I want to remove "a" from the stream and store 33 into an int, how to do this using cin.ignore?

Edits:

To be more precise:so If I have input:

```
2
3
4a
b
```

or

```
2
3
4
a
b
```

I want to store those 2,3,4 into an array, and also when encountered 'a'(first non-int char), ignore 'a', and then jumped out the input reading loop(ie

```
 while(cin>>num)
```

)?

Comment: Using `int x; cin >> x;` and inputting `33a` will give `x == 33`. Why does that not work for you?

Comment: @pingul The existence of "a" will signal an error and cause the next extraction to fail.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR version based on question edit:

The smart way is to use a `std::vector` to store the read values and ignore all the messiness of an array of unknown size.

Then

```
while not done
    read a value
    if value successfully read
        store value
        ignore to the end of the line
    else
        clear stream error
        ignore to the end of the line
```

I'm only providing a pseudocode answer because this looks too much like a homework assignment at this point. All of the required bits and pieces are discussed below and it's up to OP to assemble them correctly.

If you MUST use an array, before storing a value test to make sure you will not overrun the end of the array by storing the value.

## Old answer:

[Link to documentation.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)

`cin.ignore()` ignores one character.

`cin.ignore(10)` ignores up to 10 characters.

`cin.ignore(10, ' ')` ignores up to 10 characters or it finds and consumes a space.

Another common case is discarding the rest of the line: `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')`

So...

```
int val;
cin >>val;
cin.ignore();
```

will handle the simple case of reading an int and discarding the next character. Input of "33a" will result in 33 being stored in `val`, 'a' being ignored, and the end of line (enter keypress) used to trigger this chain of events is left in `cin` for future consumption. This could be a problem so,

```
int val;
cin >>val;
cin.ignore((std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

will read 33 into `val`, discard 'a` and anything else the user typed in. This may not be what you want. For example, input of "33a 44b"

```
int val;
cin >>val;
cin.ignore((std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ' ');
```

will read 33 into `val`, discard 'a' and anything else the user typed in up to the first space. Another pass through the above code will result in 44 in `val`, the discard of 'b', and the end of line staying in `cin`.

Attempting to use `std::getline` at this point is bad. It will instantly consume the end of line and return an empty string. However, a third pass though the above code will discard the end of line as whitespace and wait for more input from the user.

However users are lousy sources of input, so you want to protect `cin >>val;` from a user typing in something like "blah", hitting enter, and trying again. "blah cannot convert to an `int`, so `cin` will be set into the error state and you need to acknowledge this before continuing.

```
int val;
while (!(cin >>val)) // continue as long as the user has finger trouble
{
    cin.clear() // clear the error state
    // discard the rest of the line because who knows what other garbage is on it.
    cin.ignore((std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    // probably want to notify the user and prompt for good input here.
}
//whichever ignore code fits your usecase
```

or similar will handle the bad input case.

Comment: Doing this for each and every variable would be tedious. I think it's better to take input as a string, then convert each white space separated argument into an int.

Comment: Whether you get `string` and parse `string` to `int` or get `int` and `ignore` garbage you're going to wind up with similar blah because everything must be tested. Either way most of the code duplication is easily eliminated with a `int readint(istream & in)` function.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not immediately obvious now to do it, streams actually incorporate a way to deal with this quite directly (at least assuming I've understood the question correctly).

When you read (for example) a number from a stream, the stream skips any white-space before the number. To figure out whether a character is white-space or not, the stream uses an associated locale--specifically, the locale's `ctype` facet.

To have the stream ignore everything except digits, we can provide a locale that classifies everything except digits as white space.

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

class my_ctype : public std::ctype<char> {
public:
    mask const *get_table() { 
        static std::vector<std::ctype<char>::mask> 
            table(table_size, (mask)space);
        std::fill_n(table.begin() + '0', 10, (mask)digit);

        return &table[0];
    }
    my_ctype(size_t refs=0) : std::ctype<char>(get_table(), false, refs) { }
};

int main() { 
    std::istringstream s("1 2, 9 3 a 4b 2 5");
    s.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new my_ctype));

    int i;
    while (s >> i)
        std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

Result:

```
1
2
9
3
4
2
5
```

Note that with this, we don't have to use `ignore` (or anything else, except the normal stream extractor) to ignore the garbage we don't care about in the stream. The other side of this is that this is useful (at least primarily) when assigned to the stream as a whole. If you want to read 4 numbers this way, then be able to go back to reading everything normally, this probably won't be a useful technique for your situation.